# Allow Visibility to Database with Custom Permissions

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been searching Google up and down and I feel I'm close to the solution, but I don't know how else to search for my situation.

### Criteria

- I need to create a user (let's call it User_A) which will only have access to one view in only one database
- User_A should not have access to read any other data in our database
- User_A should not be able to see any of the databases on the sql server when using SSMS or other tool, except for this one database it has access to

### What I Have Found

- Created User_A
- Gave User_A `Connect` permissions on the server and database
- Created `Database Role` on database with `SELECT` permissions on the view
- Assigned User_A to the mentioned `Database Role`

Here is where I am stuck where after many hours of researching I found out about `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO User_A`. However, my research has basically lead me to where the user needs to have `db_owner` to view the database in SSMS. Obviously, that's not feasible, unless there's a way to easily deny access to everything, except to the view.

### Problem

How can I allow User_A to view the one and only database it has custom access to if they decide to use SSMS or other similar tools?

### Compromise

If I have to `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC` and work my way back editing every user to regain visibility to their respective databases I will. I just need to know the best way to handle this and I'll use the solution(s) that fit my requirements.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why in the world do you want a user who only has access to a single view to be using SSMS??? The databases will always be available in the dropdown in SSMS but when choosing one they don't have access to it will fail making the connection. Seems to me a user with that much restriction has no right knowing the database connection info.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for a very nonconstructive comment. You see, we have a 3rd party vendor who need access to some of our data. This data will suffice by displaying it in a view. We may add further views in the future. The reason why I want to prevent visibility on SSMS is so that when the 3rd party company uses connects to us via Linked Server they don't see what they don't need to see. And if a co-worker becomes curious they won't necessarily see things they don't have to. What is wrong with being more/overly secure? In the future, please try to help instead of criticize.

Comment: The databases will always be available in the dropdown in SSMS but when choosing one they don't have access to it will fail making the connection. You can allow connection on the one database you want and only allow read to the one view you want them to have access to.

Comment: Thanks. Ok interesting. How do other service providers do it when I know I'm in a shared SQL SERVER environment but I only see my databases? Is this a cause of `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC` but my user account has `db_owner`? or is there another mechanism I'm not familiar with?

Comment: I don't know of any way to prevent the dropdown from displaying all the databases on the instance. Even those you don't have to access to.

Comment: Here is a good article on the topic. https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/19/for-shared-sql-server-providers-hiding-your-list-of-databases-from-customers

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it.

Comment: @SeanLange, so I looked into the article. It reaffirms as I suspected concerning the `db_owner` and `Deny...` I guess for now this will work just fine. However, I just found out the 3rd party company gave me read only access to their DB and I can only see the 1 db I have access to on their servers. I'll find out what they did and let you guys know.

Comment: Followup: the 3rd party company would not give me any info on their setup. I assume this is not possible under one `Sql Instance`?